# Visual Studio Addon that can warn developers when it detects that certain kind of references have just been added to a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

We've all done it. We create a new class and type away the constructor adding dependencies and what not. Resharper is there to offer a helping hand and add missing references for us. It's only later on that we realise that we auto-imported references to other parts of our project that we shouldn't have.

So is there an addon for VS that one can configure (using wildcards etc) to have it issue warnings when/if certain .csproj projects are found to contain references to other .csproj projects that they aren't "allowed" to access (architecturally speaking).

Addendum: I am aware that I can achieve this by using pre-build msbuild-logic which parses the .csproj file using regexes and of course this would work. But I just find it kind of ... cumbersome and non-intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there an addon for VS that one can configure (using wildcards
>   etc) to have it issue warnings when/if certain .csproj projects are
>   found to contain references to other .csproj projects

AFAIK there's no such kind of extension that does the checking and warning job for you.

The reference to .csproj is actually project references in visual studio.

You can `right-click project=>Build Dependencies=>Project Dependencies` to check if current project depends on other projects in same solution.But this option will check both project references(`add reference to xx.csproj in current.csproj`) and project dependencies(`ProjectDependencies section in .sln`). So only use `project references` in your solution to manage dependencies between projects, then this option can easily check project references for you.

If the pre-build msbuild-logic which works need **similar** changes in every project in the solution, maybe [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) can make some help if the changes in the project file have similar format. Fetch the pre-build logic into it and put this file in solution or repos directory, it reduces **duplicate content** in every project file.